# I have 2 buttons in one activity. When I click on them, I make new intents so I can make a new screen. One works, the other doesn't

Tags: java, android

**My java code**:

```
 Button equations = (Button) findViewById(R.id.algebrabutton);
    equations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
             algebra_activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });


    Button word = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wordbutton);
    word.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view1) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view1.getContext(), 
               word_activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
        }
    });
```

**Error log** :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lawrencej.mathappdeluxe/com.exampl‌​e.lawrencej.mathappd‌​eluxe.algebra_activi‌​ty}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead
```

When I click the word button, it works fine and displays a new screen.  When I click the equations button, the app crashes.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show your error Log.

Comment: Theres no error on android studio, the app just crashes on my phone so I dont know if there is an error log

Comment: The error log is in Android Studio... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lawrencej.mathappdeluxe/com.example.lawrencej.mathappdeluxe.algebra_activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: oh I see so apparently I just cant have a toolbar.  Well this fixes my problem, thanks for pointing out where the error log is :)

Comment: You can check my answer.@LarryJing

Comment: @KeLiuyue I don't need to add those, I added a toolbar by myself because I wanted the extra addon, but apparently I can't.  It doesnt have a toolbar by default. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: What is wrong with my questions? I am now question banned... instead of just downvoting can people tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `styles` code .

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in your `manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name=".algebra_activity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```